# Which tool can show various threads and stack info in the already running java code?

Tags: java

I would like to know tools to check thread/stack information in both windows platform, Linux platform and Mac platform which jvm is running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html)**, which comes bundled with JDK 6 release 7.

Answer (score 2):

[JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) might be what you are looking for.
Combine it with [TopThreads](http://lsd.luminis.nl/top-threads-plugin-for-jconsole/) to get more features. Here is a small [tutorial](http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/05/java-cpu-usage-profiling.html) on how to use TopThreads with JConsole